# .fbx rig exporting

Tags: animation, rigging, export, .fbx, scale

I'm trying to export animation for a project and when I finish my animation it looks fine. When I export everything and import it again for testing,I get weird scaling and rotation in my animation that wasn't there before for any animations where the character turns around.

Before (sorry for tearing capture):

[image]

After export:

[image]

This rig comes from a re-purposed biped rig where I just extended the fingers and have it in IK mode constantly.

I've tried baking out all my animation(Both with the add on that does visible keying and the stock Key > Bake Curve)

I've went to key>sampling to set keyframes on every frame.

I've baked in both Euler and Quaternion

I've set the Smoothing settings to 0.0 in the .fbx export settings

I'm not sure what else to do aside from trying to rebuild the front legs, but I don't think the animations would transfer very well, and I don't want to reanimate all the animations.

Also, I noticed that no matter what I export my rotations as (XYZ euler rotate or Quaternion) it always imports as Quaternion

Comment: I figured out a work around. I selected my Deformation bones and used the Back Action tool under the Animation tab to do a Visual Keying bake on all my animations. Then on the last bake, I checked the 'Clear Constraints' and 'Clear Parents' box so my control rig wouldn't affect my Deformation joints.

Comment: ... I then set all the scaling on the joints to 1 after deleting all the scaling animation. After that when I did the FBX export, I unchecked the 'Key All Bones' checkbox so it wouldn't add any extra stuff. There are still a bit of gimble in the animation, but its a start so far.        (Sorry I accidentally pushed Enter too many times and you can only edit a response 5 times)